# How to make Styled components generic to receive parameters?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to use Styled Components with React FC. I want to display few details inside a div container, which all has the same stylings. Instead of writing hard coded such as Name: Height: Weight: etc. in the h-tags, can I do it in a more generic way to pass the text as parameter?

This is the way I have implemented, but I am thinking there should be some better way to do it. Like giving a parameter to the Styled component.

```
const CardContentContainer= styled.div`
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
`;

const CardContentDetails = styled.h3`
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
`;
```

this is the code inside the return:

```
return (

 <CardContentContainer>
    <CardContentDetails>
      Name: {ItemDetails?.name}
    </CardContentDetails>
    <CardContentDetails>
      Height:{ItemDetails?.height}
    </CardContentDetails>
    <CardContentDetails>
      Weight:{ItemDetails?.weight}
    </CardContentDetails>
  </CardContentContainer>
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant pass such props to Styled components because the main point of SC is to apply a custom style to that component. To make it receive some custom props, you have to wrap it inside another component like so...

```
const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)`
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 20em;
`;

const Comp: React.FC<{ title: string }> = ({ title }) => (
  <StyledTextField>{title}</StyledTextField>
);

return (
  <Comp title="some title" />
```

Comment: Yes, I use Typescript. My point is, how to send a parameter instead of hard coding in an h3 tag. For instance: something like this <CardContentDetails title={Name: }>

Comment: in that case you have to make it a react functional component

Comment: I am using function component.

Comment: made an edit to my post @Waiz

Comment: Thanks. This is closer to what I need. So basically I need to create a separate component for this.

Comment: yes, thats correct !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238429/discussion-between-waiz-and-oliver-ilmjarv).